# Maximo 7.6.0.10 Automation Script Error Messages dont work properly after Websphere V9.0.5.3 upgrade

Tags: javascript, websphere, rhino, nashorn, maximo

After upgrading websphere to version 9, I had to add the load("nashhorn:mozilla_compat.js") line to get alot of my javascript autoscripts to work. After continued testing I have noticed that atleast alot of if not all the errors called through these autoscripts no longer work. Instead they show the generic BMXAA4214E An unknown error has occured message instead of the one called in the script. There seems to be other classes that no longer work since the upgrade as well but that is a question for another time.

```
function checklo14(mbo) {
    if (!mbo.isNull("lo14")) {
        var retVal = checkValue(mbo.getString("lo14"));

        if (retVal == false) {
            service.log("LOCATIONSLO14VAL.JS - concession syntax is invalid: " + mbo.getString("lo14") + " - throwing exception");
            service.error("test", "concessionsyntax");
        } else {
            service.log("LOCATIONSLO14VAL.JS - concession syntax is ok: " + mbo.getString("lo14"));
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I have included the above function as an example of a call to service.error but even in an autoscript with just that service.error line it will come up as BMXAA4214E. Any help is appreciated. I wish I could find some good documentation on Maximo Autoscripts in 7.6.1 escpecially for javascript.

Comment: Your title is about Maximo 7.6.0.10, but at the end of your question you mention Maximo Autoscripts ... 7.6.1. Is one of those a mistake? And do your logs show any other errors or give more info in the stack trace?

Comment: Clearly it would be less than ideal, but can you get the error to be thrown the "old" way, by setting `errorgroup` and `errorkey` variables to the error you want to throw and let your script "end" normally?

Comment: And, have you raised a Support Case with IBM?